# Forcing traffic to ASP.NET page on a specific web server

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, replication

We have an asp.net web application in which is replicated to 3 different IIS web servers for load balancing. For the sake of this example, I will create fictitious IP addresses and geographical locations (US States) for each server.

Web Server 1: `192.168.0.1`, location: MD

Web Server 2: `192.168.0.2`, location: NY

Web Server 3: `192.168.0.3`, location: TX

When a user visits our domain, let's call it `www.foo.com`, the web server that handles their request depends on their geographical location. For instance, if the user is closest to NY then the server that will handle their request will be Server 2. This process is transparent to the end user, the end user simply types `http://www.foo.com` into their browser's address bar and the appropriate web server is requested behind the scenes.

The problem we have is that we have a specific asp.net page `http://www.foo.com/map.aspx` in the application that uses a third party control. The third party control's license is installed only on Server 1. We do not have any other licenses. So if a user requests the `map.aspx` page, we need to direct them to Server 1, regardless of the user's geographic location.

The question I have is what is the best way to do this? Should this be handled by IIS at the web server level or by the web application?

I thought about URL Rewriting via the web application based on incoming requests.

Comment: Configure that handles the _"the web server that handles their request depends on their geographical location"_ logic, in other words: check your load balancer's configuration manual.

Comment: @Lloyd, an exception in the load balancer sounds like a good solution, the question is, how? PS, I'm not a systems guy, I'm a .NET developer.

Comment: We don't know what solution is used, please ask your the one responsible.